# SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized (paramiko module)

Tags: python

I have problems when running the script, I have also installed paramiko but still can't run the script. and I've put curly brackets () on line 29, maybe it still doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2rgl.png)

I have also tried using kali linux but the result is still the same

Comment: Please add snippet of the code to understand what you have done. From looking at just the error:Change line to except Exception as msg:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for `openssh_crypt_cpu_consumption_dos.py` I stumbled upon [`exploit-database/exploits/linux/dos/40888.py`](https://github.com/natrix-fork/exploit-database/blob/ef96c0511bf7e43703e613053857d0d3ef1bf22f/exploits/linux/dos/40888.py#L60) :

```py
        except Exception, msg:
```

Which looks like Python2 syntax. Edit the script, as suggested by @BhavinT, but in this way :

```
-        except Exception, msg:
+        except Exception as msg:
```

Comment: @BhavinT still the same error, I've changed a few. 
in this script source https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40888

Comment: this time the error is from string import lowercase
ImportError: cannot import name 'lowercase' from 'string' (/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/string.py)

Comment: It seems the entire code base is in Python 2, you should not try to run it with Python3. Quick fixes won't solve every problem.

Comment: I'll try again if I can, thanks for helping